# NppFTP always times out the first attempt to upload

Tags: ftp, notepad++

To save a file to the server that I've edited with Notepad++ I right click the remote folder in the NppFTP pane that I want to upload to and select "Upload current file here."  But if I haven't uploaded anything for a while,  I have to wait about 10 seconds for this first attempt to time out and then when I do the same thing again it works.  If I upload several files one after another, it works for each one after the first one.

Does anyone have an idea why this connection is getting dropped and then has to time out once to get connected again?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the bug is, but my work around is to save the file, then just make a small modification to the file, like add a space at the end of any line. This then means that the file has to be uploaded again. The first attempted upload is sitting in the queue, and it will fail. My computer gives an audio "pongle" noise, then a second or so uploads the second file. 
If you have not uploaded for a significant time, just disconnect, then re-connect, open folders etc and start again. It's a pain, I know, but it's free, isn't it?